# Не могу передать значения Combobox и Entry в функцию. Python tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

В Python, тем более в tkinter я новичок, пишу калькулятор калорий в качестве семестровой работы. Возникла проблема передачи значений dishes_box.get() и grams.get() из дочернего окна, которое вызвано функцией, в функцию add_a_dish(), которая является командой для кнопки. Пробовал использовать и lambda выражения и функцию partial, но результата не добился.

```
def choose_dish(name, massa):
    name = dishes_box.get()
    base_of_dishes = open('dishes.txt', encoding= 'UTF-8')
    for line in base_of_dishes:
        line = line.split(',')
        if line[0] == str(name):
            bilok_now = float(line[1]) * (float(massa)/100)
            jir_now = float(line[2]) * (float(massa)/100)
            vyg_now = float(line[3]) * (float(massa)/100)
            calories_now = float(line[4]) * (float(massa)/100)
            break
            base_of_dishes.close()


def add_a_dish():
    
    

    a = []
    base_of_dishes = open('dishes.txt', encoding= 'UTF-8')
    for line in base_of_dishes:
        line = line.split(',')
        a.append(str(line[0]))
    base_of_dishes.close()
    
    grams = tk.IntVar()
    
    window = tk.Toplevel(master=calculator_window)
    window.geometry('300x200')
    window.title('Додати страву')
    
    tk.Label(window ,text='Оберіть страву з списку введіть її приблизну вагу:', font = 'Arial 8').pack()
    
    dishes_box = tk.ttk.Combobox(window, values=a)
    dishes_box.pack()
    x = dishes_box.get()
    tk.Label(window, text='Вага в грамах:').pack()
    tk.Entry(window, textvariable=grams).pack()
    tk.Button(window, text='ОК', command = partial(choose_dish, x, grams.get())).pack(pady=10)
```

Заранее благодарен)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `partial` нужно использовать лямбду, т.к. у вас методы `.get` от полей вызываются сразу при создании кнопки, а нужно чтобы вызывались только после нажатия на кнопку:

```
tk.Button(window, text='ОК', command=lambda: choose_dish(dishes_box.get(), grams.get())).pack(pady=10)
```

Ну и в `choose_dish` убрать строку `name = dishes_box.get()`, т.к. название уже передается через параметр `name`.

Comment: спасибо большое, но снова возникла проблема с `NameError: name 'dishes_box' is not defined`.

Comment: @АнтонЯгущин сделали то что в последнем предложении написано?

Comment: Да, тепер другая ошибка - `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: В какой строке?

Comment: `tk.Button(window, text='ОК', command=lambda: choose_dish(dishes_box.get(), grams.get())).pack(pady=10)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: Значит у вас либо dishes_box, либо grams где-то значением None перезаписано. В приведенном в вопросе коде я такого не вижу. Возможно вы переделали `dishes_box = tk.ttk.Combobox(window, values=a)` и `dishes_box.pack()` в одну строку, в итоге в `dishes_box` записывается результат вызова `pack()`, а не комбобокс.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все исправил, теперь работает. Рейтинга не хватит для того, чтобы вам поставить +, но чем богаты)